# Cached queries on Snowflake console not cached when using snowflake-jdbc

Tags: caching, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've noticed that some simple queries ("select * from ") that are cached on the Snowflake web console are not cached when I issue the exact same query via JDBC. Is this to be expected? (Using the same user and role as well.)

Comment: The result set cache works for JDBC and other connectors if all criteria are met. However, even if all criteria are met, there is no guarantee a query will use the result set cache. You can see the requirements that must be met for the possibility of using the result set cache at this page in the docs: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-persisted-results.html#retrieval-optimization

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to make sure all the parameters are the same, so I might be in the "no guarantee" zone... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you were using the parameter USE_CACHED_RESULT? 
There are several parameters for session or connection which make the JDBC access different from the GUI behaviour.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#connection-parameters

Comment: Thanks --- I did check it, and it is set to `TRUE`.